# Unable to click input type="file" in windows safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, safari

Here is my html code

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="UPLOAD" />
<input id="fileupload" type="file" style="display:none;" />
```

here is jquery code

```
 $('#btn').click(function () {
            $('#fileupload').click();
        });
```

It works as expected in Chrome and in windows safari doesn't do any thing.And i checked no error in console.
Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AZwjd/)

Comment: Does it work if the `fileupload` element isn't hidden?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try hiding input file using the below code instead of `display:none;`

```
 opacity:0;width:0px;height:0px;
```

Comment: dats nice...i guess opacity alone will do ...no need of setting width and height to 0

Comment: try clicking around the immediate empty space near the button, you will end up clicking the file element by mistake(which is not visible), i.e. why better set width and height to 0px as a precaution :)

Comment: never thought dat..thnks anywaz :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
input[type="file"] {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
```