# File input javascript click not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I'm trying to programmatically open a file input from javascript and it's not working in Safari (13.0.5).  This file input is not hidden or anything.  I've tried all these different ways so far:

```
<input type="file" id="markupImport"></input>

$('#markupImport').click()
$('#markupImport').trigger('click')

document.getElementById('markupImport').click()
document.getElementById('markupImport').trigger('click')

event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents')
event.initEvent('click', true, false)
$('#markupImport')[0].dispatchEvent(event)
document.getElementById('markupImport').dispatchEvent(event)

event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents')
event.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window)
$('#markupImport')[0].dispatchEvent(event)
document.getElementById('markupImport').dispatchEvent(event)

document.getElementById('markupImport').dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))
```

I've looked at [In JavaScript can I make a "click" event fire programmatically for a file input element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input), [calling click event of input doesn't work in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501221/calling-click-event-of-input-doesnt-work-in-safari), [Unable to click input type="file" in windows safari browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18531196/unable-to-click-input-type-file-in-windows-safari-browser), [Programmatically trigger "select file" dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595389/programmatically-trigger-select-file-dialog-box), and all the others I can find already.

I'm trying to do this from a `select` `onchange` handler when a certain option is selected:

```
<select id="markupImport">
  <option value="Import">Import</option>
  <option value="Export">Export</option>
</select>
<input type="file" id="markupImport"></input>

$(function() {
  $('#markupImport').change(function(event) {
    if (event.target.value == 'Import') {
      $('input[name="markupImport"]').click();
    }
  });
});
```

I'm wondering if it's not even possible to do this in Safari anymore.

Comment: So you're trying to programmatically trigger a click event to open the file dialog?

Comment: Correct. I'm using a select dropdown to call some JS to do this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically trigger "select file" dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595389/programmatically-trigger-select-file-dialog-box)

Comment: @mwilson, that answer is the same as `$('#markupImport').click()` above which I said I already tried and doesn't work in Safari

Comment: It seems like this might have to do with Safari not allowing a select changed event to be used to trigger opening the file upload.  If I have a button instead with an `onclick` handler that clicks the file input, it does open

Comment: @kmanzana how did you manage to solve your issue?

document.getElementById("uploadGalleryPhoto").click() not working for me in ios?

Comment: @sinan, sorry I missed this earlier. I don't recall what I did, but I might have just used a button instead of trying to be fancy about it as Safari isn't very lenient